# Can't boot OS from USB on Samsung Series 7

Tags: system-installation, samsung

1. I downloaded the ISO and burned it via unetbootin.
2. I go into BIOS and change the following settings:

   > disable fast boot, and make the OS selection CMS
   >   make USB boot first
3. Then when I boot, it just boots back to Windows8.

I have a "Samsung Series 7 Chronos" with nividia graphics. --Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you save the changes made in bios?

Comment: yes, i save and exit

Comment: Did you confirm the md5 on your ISO prior to using it with unetbootin?